# Modifying variable attribute of netcdf file

Tags: netcdf, nco, cdo-climate

I'm trying to modify the calendar type of a time variable in a netcdf file to change from `GREGORIAN` to `gregorian` as I think it is causing problems when I try to access the time variables within a later analysis.

```
        double Time(Time) ;
                Time:long_name = "Time" ;
                Time:units = "days since 1979-01-01 00:00:00" ;
                Time:cartesian_axis = "T" ;
                Time:calendar_type = "GREGORIAN" ;
                Time:calendar = "GREGORIAN" ;
                Time:bounds = "Time_bounds" ;
                Time:_ChunkSizes = 1 ;
```

to

```
        double Time(Time) ;
                Time:long_name = "Time" ;
                Time:units = "days since 1979-01-01 00:00:00" ;
                Time:cartesian_axis = "T" ;
                Time:calendar_type = "gregorian" ;
                Time:calendar = "gregorian" ;
                Time:bounds = "Time_bounds" ;
                Time:_ChunkSizes = 1 ;
```

I have tried to use the nco function nccat but I can't seem to get the syntax correct. I tried:

```
ncatted -a 'calendar,time,o,c,"gregorian"' Ocean_v_1994_01.nc out.nc
```

Comment: While you are at it, I suggest adding a `standard_name` attribute to the `Time` variable, with attribute value `time`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The single quotes you placed around the `ncatted` argument causes the double quotes to become literals which is not what you want. There are no literals, spaces, or special characters in your argument, so just drop all quotes:

ncatted -a calendar,time,o,c,gregorian Ocean_v_1994_01.nc out.nc

Comment: Amazing thank you! slight change to be `Time` rather than `time` to get it to work

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to do this using R and the ncdf4 package. The solution was:

```
library(ncdf4)
mydata <- nc_open("Ocean_v_1994_01.nc", write = TRUE)

ncatt_put(mydata, "Time", 'calendar', attval = 'gregorian', prec = 'text')
ncatt_put(mydata, "Time", 'calendar_type', attval = 'gregorian', prec = 'text')

# check result 
ncatt_get(mydata, "Time")

nc_sync(mydata)
nc_close(mydata)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could also sort this by using the cdo setcalendar command:

```
 cdo setcalendar,proleptic_gregorian in.nc out.nc
```